# Attempting to create pdf/a from pdf using ghostscript gswin8.56 32bit

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdfa

I am trying to convert pdf to pdf/a using the following command on windows server 2012 r2.

```
gswin32c.exe -dPDFA=1 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE
-sColorConversionStrategy=/RGB -sOutputICCProfile=AdobeRGB1998.icc \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output_a.pdf -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 \
PDFA_def.ps inputput.pdf

Prior to this I changed the icc profile in PDFA_def.ps to AdobeRGB1998.icc.
When I run the command I get the following Post Script error message.

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false 1 %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1140/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:70/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 8.56: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

I have been beating my head on this for quiet long now. Any help to resolve this error would be highly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do this with a version of Ghostscript that old (8.56 is now 9 years old). The current released version is 9.20, upgrade.

You should also ensure that you have specified the **full** path of the ICC profile in the modified pdfa_def.ps.